# Catalog Price Rule For Bundle Items

Tags: magento

I have some bundle products whose based price is set to 0 and the Price type is set to FIXED, the reason why I have it like that is I would want the bundle product price to be calculated from its pieces/items only.

Now when I try apply the price rules, it does not apply to the bundle products, is there a way to apply catalog price rules to Bundle product items only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It does work, it's just possibly a little convoluted on how to make sure things are applied.

1. Make sure you're actually applying the rule once you've made it. When viewing the rule itself, make sure to hit 'Save and Apply' - or, on the rules list page, hit 'Apply Rules'.
2. I tested this in a sandbox, and used a new product attribute to hook into and control the price rule. If you go this route, make sure the attribute has 'Use for Promo Rule Conditions' is applied.

I tested this in 1.6.2 and it's working fine.

Comment: "Save and Apply!" How could I miss that!

Comment: Please read above, base price of my  Bundle product is zero and its total price is calculated based on its items, so if I would want to offer a discount of 5% on the bundle item how it is going to reflect on its items? 

I know that process but it only works for items which has a base price and it is applied to that.